# How to remote login a user on windows 7 computer? (Not RDP)

Tags: windows-7, login, remote

Sometimes i need to login about 30 computers (windows 7). 
I used vnc to connect each computer and type the username and password to login.
Wondering is there a way to use command line control those 30 computers to login a user at once...?
Thank you!
I googled remote login windows 7 but the result are about RDP. I need to login to the console not remote session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First log in to RDP. Then move your session from RDP to console using:

```
tscon <source_session> /dest:<target_session>
```

For the source session (yours), use either its numeric ID (e.g. 3) or current name (e.g. rdp-tcp#6). Either `qwinsta` or `quser` will tell you both; your current entry is marked with a `>`.

For the target session always use its name, `console`. For example:

```
tscon rdp-tcp#6 /dest:console
```

The command requires Administrator privileges.

---

(The numeric 'session ID' remains static during the session's lifetime but the 'session name' changes depending on where it's attached. For example, disconnecting from RDP will remove the name, and reconnecting will assign a different one again.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much grawity!
Sorry for late reply, I just have time to test it out recently.
I made a bat now it can logon to 30 computers automatically.
(note: psexec and nircmd required).
First I have to save the `.rdp` infomation for every computers.
Then here's the bat script.

`nircmd exec hide mstsc computer-01.rdp
nircmd exec hide mstsc computer-02.rdp
nircmd exec hide mstsc computer-03.rdp
...`

After this part you may have to wait a few seconds for connecting RDP to all computer, use `pause` or `nircmd cmdwait 10000`(10 seconds).

`psexec \\computer-01 -s -i -d tscon rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console
psexec \\computer-02 -s -i -d tscon rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console
psexec \\computer-03 -s -i -d tscon rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console
...`

Thank you again!